# How to let your data from entry and date save under respective columns in tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

i have this code to save what i entered in the entry filed in a csv file together with the period <"date and time"> i entered the data but my challenge is the period and the data entered saves under same column heading.

How can i make it so that the date will save under column DATE and data entered save under column INPUT and also the time saves as a "#####" and only in AM even when i perform the task at night.

```
import csv
import os
from tkinter import *
import time



with open ("TP.csv", "w") as db:
    writer = csv.writer(db)
    writer.writerow(["DATE", "INPUT"])# Create the file with this as heading


def current_date_time(): # the time saves only in am aven when i perform the task at night
    display = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y  %I:%M:%S', time.localtime())
    with open ("TP.csv", "a") as csvfile:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile)
        w.writerow([display])


def save_print_data():
    global e3
    data = e3.get()
    with open ("TP.csv", "a") as savedb:
        w = csv.writer(savedb)
        w.writerow([data])


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


profile = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(width=50, textvariable=profile)

label1 = Label(root)
b1 = Button(root, text="Print & save", command=lambda :[save_print_data(), 
current_date_time()])

e3.pack()
label1.pack()
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As for the `####` you need to expand the column size. Im just reading your code now however.

Comment: Also, your current_date_time` function, last two lines, aren't indented. Is that a mistake or?

Comment: `%I` uses a 12-hour clock. If you want a 24 hour clock use `%H`. Or use `%p` in conjunction with `%I` to get an AM / PM indicator.

Comment: You should get the time and combine it into a list with the data from the `e3` Entry. And then save that list using `writerow`.

Comment: @ Goralight thanks for prompting me have edited that

Comment: @ PM 2Ring will it save under respective column after combining in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voicing the comment of @PM 2Ring. You can join the input into one list, and one function, and place it respectively.

```
import csv
import os
from tkinter import *
import time

with open("TP.csv", "w") as db:
    writer = csv.writer(db)
    writer.writerow(["DATE", "INPUT"])# Create the file with this as heading

def save_print_data():
    global e3
    data = e3.get()
    display = time.strftime('%d/%m/%y  %I:%M:%S%p', time.localtime())
    totalinput = [display, data]
    with open("TP.csv", "a") as savedb:
        w = csv.writer(savedb)
        w.writerow(totalinput)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

profile = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(width=50, textvariable=profile)

label1 = Label(root)
b1 = Button(root, text="Print & save", command=lambda: [save_print_data()])

e3.pack()
label1.pack()
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will make a csv file which will look like:

```
DATE                    INPUT
06/11/17  10:58:17AM    test
```

I am not familiar with csv module, so i am not sure about resizing the columns, but i am checking for you now. This code however does remove the `#######` you were having and at least displays the date

Comment: %p means what i want to understand it better the function you wrote . Your answer works

Comment: @ADWAN the `%p` when used simply adds `AM` or `PM` depending on the time. Glad I could help :) besure to upvote too!

Comment: This  question has been down voted i think it will be encouraging   to state the reason for me not to repeat again.

Comment: @ADWAN - Im not sure why you got downvoted - it wasn't me. Personally your question seems valid.

Comment: Just wanted to know the cause in order not for me to repeat again